# Systemd user unit not started on login

Tags: systemd, minikube

I'm trying to launch minikube on login but it just doesn't work. I can do `systemctl --user start minikube.service`, which works just fine, but whenever I enable it and log in for the first time its status stays `enabled` and `inactive`. What am I missing?

```
[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/bin/minikube start
ExecStop=/usr/bin/minikube stop
RemainAfterExit=yes

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```